# Python module installed but getting an import error in windows

Tags: python, windows, module, installation

I installed a python module, the installation was a success. 
I installed it by changing the path in Windows powershell to the folder and then

```
python setup.py install
```

but then when i try to import that I get a error message

```
no module named yahoo_finance
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

Answer (score 1):

You don't have [yahoo_finace](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) module installed.

You can install this module by command:

> python -m pip install yahoo_finance

Here you may read more about pip:

> https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/

Comment: When I run that command I get the follwoing 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): yahoo-finance in c:\users\koushik\python\yahoo-finance-1.2.1
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from yahoo-finance)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson in c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\simplejson-3.8.2-py2.7-win-amd64.egg (from yahoo-finance)
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.